# core file size limit has non-deterministic effects on processes

Tags: c, linux, coredump

I'm running a custom 2.6.27 kernel and I just noticed the core files produced during a segfault are larger than the hard core file size limit set for processes.

And what makes it weirder is that the core file is *only sometimes* truncated (but not to the limit set by ulimit).

For example, this is the program I will try and crash below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Get the hard and soft limit from command line
    struct rlimit new = {atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[1])};

    // Create some memory so as to beef up the core file size
    void *p = malloc(10 * 1024 * 1024);

    if (!p)
        return 1;

    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &new)) // Set the hard and soft limit
        return 2;                     // for core files produced by this
                                      // process

    while (1);

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the execution:

```
Linux# ./a.out 1446462 &    ## Set hard and soft limit to ~1.4 MB
[1] 14802
Linux# ./a.out 1446462 &
[2] 14803
Linux# ./a.out 1446462 &
[3] 14804
Linux# ./a.out 1446462 &
[4] 14807

Linux# cat /proc/14802/limits | grep core
Max core file size        1446462              1446462              bytes

Linux# killall -QUIT a.out

Linux# ls -l
total 15708
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4624 Aug  1 18:28 a.out
-rw------- 1 root root 12013568 Aug  1 18:39 core.14802         <=== truncated core
-rw------- 1 root root 12017664 Aug  1 18:39 core.14803
-rw------- 1 root root 12013568 Aug  1 18:39 core.14804         <=== truncated core
-rw------- 1 root root 12017664 Aug  1 18:39 core.14807
[1]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 1446462
[2]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 1446462
[3]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 1446462
[4]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 1446462
```

So multiple things happened here. I set the hard limit for each process to be about 1.4 MB.

1. The core files produced well exceed this set limit. Why?
2. And 2 of the 4 core file produced are truncated, but by exactly `4096` bytes. What's going on here?

I know the core file contains, among other things, the full stack and heap memory allocated. Shouldn't that be pretty much constant for such a simple program (give or take a few bytes at the most), hence producing a consistent core between multiple instances?

**EDITS:**

**1**  The requested output of `du`

```
Linux# du core.*
1428    core.14802
1428    core.14803
1428    core.14804
1428    core.14807

Linux# du -b core.*
12013568    core.14802
12017664    core.14803
12013568    core.14804
12017664    core.14807
```

**2**  Adding `memset()` after `malloc()` definitely reigned things in, in that the core file are now all truncated to `1449984` (still `3522` bytes over the limit).

So why were the cores so big before, what did they contain? Whatever it was, it wasn't subjected to the process' limits.

**3** The new program shows some interesting behaviour as well:

```
Linux# ./a.out 12017664 &
[1] 26586
Linux# ./a.out 12017664 &
[2] 26589
Linux# ./a.out 12017664 &
[3] 26590
Linux# ./a.out 12017663 &        ## 1 byte smaller
[4] 26653
Linux# ./a.out 12017663 &        ## 1 byte smaller
[5] 26666
Linux# ./a.out 12017663 &        ## 1 byte smaller
[6] 26667

Linux# killall -QUIT a.out

Linux# ls -l
total ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4742 Aug  1 19:47 a.out
-rw------- 1 root root 12017664 Aug  1 19:47 core.26586
-rw------- 1 root root 12017664 Aug  1 19:47 core.26589
-rw------- 1 root root 12017664 Aug  1 19:47 core.26590
-rw------- 1 root root  1994752 Aug  1 19:47 core.26653           <== ???
-rw------- 1 root root  9875456 Aug  1 19:47 core.26666           <== ???
-rw------- 1 root root  9707520 Aug  1 19:47 core.26667           <== ???
[1]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 12017664
[2]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 12017664
[3]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 12017664
[4]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 12017663
[5]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 12017663
[6]   Quit                    (core dumped) ./a.out 12017663
```

Comment: First, what does `du` show for the actual number of bytes used by the core file?  Also, `memset()` the memory.  Simply doing a `malloc()` doesn't cause actual memory to be mapped into the process.

Comment: 4096 is the virtual memory page size. When the core dump is created, all of the vm pages assigned to the process will be dumped to the core file.  The smaller file is 2933 pages, and the larger file is 2934 pages. So that's fairly consistent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Adding `memset()` definitely made things more consistent, but not entirely. I've updated my question with that and `du` results.

Comment: @user3386109 makes sense. But gdb complains that those 2 are truncated, but the other two it's perfectly okay with. So for all 4 cores, it's expecting `12017664` bytes.

Comment: How are you compiling your program for these test?  Is it with or without optimization?

Comment: The programs got so large because they were not allocating physical memory, just virtual memory. When GLIBC's malloc() is given a large amount of memory to allocate it request to do so in another virtual memory page from the kernel. For some reason the core file is writing all of the memory, including bytes that never physically existed (this is weird since files in Linux with most file systems can leave [file holes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982478/what-is-file-hole-and-how-can-it-be-used)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation of core dumping can be found in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`.  I'll follow the code in 3.12 and above (it changed with [commit 9b56d5438](http://kernel.opensuse.org/cgit/kernel/commit/?id=9b56d54380adb5fef71f687109bbd6f8413d694f)) but the logic is very similar.

The code initially decides how much to dump of a VMA (virtual memory area) in `vma_dump_size`.  For an anonymous VMA such as the `brk` heap, it returns the full size of the VMA.  During this step, the core limit is not involved.

The first phase of writing the core dump then writes a `PT_LOAD` header for each VMA.  This is basically a pointer that says where to find the data in the remainder of the ELF file.  The actual data is written by a `for` loop, and is actually a second phase.

During the second phase, `elf_core_dump` repeatedly calls `get_dump_page` to get a `struct page` pointer for each page of the program address space that has to be dumped. `get_dump_page` is a common utility function found in `mm/gup.c`.  The comment to `get_dump_page` is helpful:

```
 * Returns NULL on any kind of failure - a hole must then be inserted into
 * the corefile, to preserve alignment with its headers; and also returns
 * NULL wherever the ZERO_PAGE, or an anonymous pte_none, has been found -
 * allowing a hole to be left in the corefile to save diskspace.
```

and in fact `elf_core_dump` calls a function in `fs/coredump.c` ( `dump_seek` in your kernel, `dump_skip` in 3.12+) if `get_dump_page` returns `NULL`.  This function calls lseek to leave a hole in the dump (actually since this is the kernel it calls `file->f_op->llseek` directly on a `struct file` pointer).  **The main difference is that `dump_seek` was indeed not obeying the ulimit, while the newer `dump_skip` does.**

As to why the second program has the weird behavior, it's probably because of ASLR (address space randomization).  Which VMA is truncated depends on the relative order of the VMAs, which is random.  You could try disabling it with

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

and see if your results are more homogeneous.  To reenable ASLR, use

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```