# What is a sparse file and why do we need it?

Tags: file, filesystems, system, disk, sparse-file

What is a sparse file and why do we need it?
The only thing that I am able to get is that it is a very large file and it is efficient(in gigabytes). How is it efficient ?

Comment: As far as I understood the technology behind is, if you have big files with a lot blocks of 0 bytes (e.g. you are calculating the position for storing data with a hash algorythm) the operating system will not allocate blocks of 0 bytes, only the data you need. I never used it before, because I never had a task like I described.

Comment: blocks of 0 bytes? please explain @nabuchodonossor

Comment: Ok, you also could google (microsoft ntfs sparse file) and find the explanation from there, but you asked, so I copy & paste a bit: "A file in which much of the data is zeros is said to contain a sparse data set. Files like these are typically very large—for example, a file that contains image data to be processed or a matrix within a high-speed database. The problem with files that contain sparse data sets is that the majority of the file does not contain useful data and, because of this, they are an inefficient use of disk space...."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Say you have a file with many empty bytes `\x00`. These many empty bytes `\x00` are called holes. Storing empty bytes is just not efficient, we know there are many of them in the file, so why store them on the storage device? We could instead store metadata describing those zeros. When a process reads the file those zero byte blocks get generated dynamically as opposed to being stored on physical storage (look at this schematic from Wikipedia):

[image: Sparse File - Wikipedia]

This is why a sparse file is efficient, because it does not store the zeros on disk, instead it holds enough data describing the zeros that will be generated.

**Note:** the logical file size is greater than the physical file size for sparse files. This is because we have not stored the zeros physically on a storage device.

---

**Edit:**

When you run:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=output bs=1G count=4
```

The command here copies 4G blocks of null bytes to `output`. To see that:

```
$ stat output
File: ouput
  Size: 4294967296      Blocks: 8388616    IO Block: 4096   regular file
--omitted--
```

You can see that this file has *8388616* blocks allocated to it, these blocks store nothing but *empty bytes* copied from `/dev/zero` and they do occupy physical disk space, they're holes stored on disk (sparse zeros). `dd` did what you asked for, copying blocks of data from one file to another.

Now, run this command to detect the holes and make the file sparse in-place:

```
$ fallocate -d output
$ stat output
File: swapfile
  Size: 4294967296      Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
--omitted--
```

Do you notice something? The the number of blocks now is 0 because the blocks that were storing only empty bytes were de-allocated. Remember, `output`'s blocks store nothing, only a bunch of empty zeros, `fallocate -d` detected the blocks that contain only empty zeros and deallocated them, since all the blocks for this file contain zeros, they were all de-allocated.

Also notice how the size remained the same. This is the logical (virtual) size of the file, not its size on disk. It's crucial to know that `output` doesn't occupy *physical* storage space now, it has 0 blocks allocated to it and thus I doesn't really use disk space. The size preserved after running `fallocate -d` so when you later read from the file, you get the empty bytes generated to you by the filesystem at runtime. The physical size of `output` however, is zero, *it uses no data blocks.*

Remember, when you read `output` file the empty bytes are generated by the filesystem at runtime dynamically, they're *not* really physically stored on disk, and the file's size as reported by `stat` is the logical size, and the physical size is zero for `output`. In this case the filesystem has to generate 4G of empty bytes when a process reads the file.

To generate a sparse file using `dd`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=output2 bs=1G seek=0 count=0
$ stat 
stat output2
  File: output2
  Size: 4294967296      Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

GNU `dd` internally uses `lseek` and `ftruncate`, so check truncate(2) and lseek(2).

Comment: so, when we make a file with this method, `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4`, so this file will have zero size on disk ?  right ?

Comment: When you make a file with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4` it will not have a zero size on disk. Because `dd` copies the zero bytes to your file. In other words, you've actually copied the zero bytes from `/dev/zero` to `/swapfile`. This command however, `dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse_file bs=1G seek=4 count=0` makes a sparse file, you could run `stat` on both files and see how the `Blocks` field changes. Your command is the recommended way to make a swap file.

Comment: If you run `fallocate -d /swapfile` this command makes a swap file in-place, removing  all the null bytes data blocks allocated to `/swapfile`. Again you can check with `stat /swapfile` after your run `fallocate` command, see what happens to the number of allocated blocks. However, don't do this to a swap file, make the test on another file.

Comment: You - "Because dd copies the zero bytes to your file". But these are still zero bytes. Why don't they act like holes here ? If you could point me where this is explained OR if you could edit your answer to clarify my doubt.

Comment: @Luv33preet I've edited my answer. they're holes (just sparse zeros) stored on disk, as such the file is not sparse. A sparse file uses disk space efficiently by not storing the sparse zeros on disk.

Comment: @direprobs I attempted to edit your last example to match your comment. The text in the answer does not work as intended. However the edit was rejected. Please approve the edit or make it yourself, I'm sure it was just a copy paste error.

Answer (score 10):

A sparse file is a file that is mostly empty, i.e. it contains large blocks of bytes whose value is `0` (zero).

On the disk, the content of a file is stored in blocks of fixed size (usually 4 KiB or more). When all the bytes contained in such a block are `0`, a file system that implements sparse files does not store the block on disk, instead it keeps the information somewhere in the file meta-data.

Advantages of using sparse files:

- empty blocks of data do not occupy disk space; they are not stored as the regular blocks of data, their identifiers (that use only several bytes) are stored instead in the file meta-data; this way 4 KiB of disk space (or more) are saved for each empty block;
- reading an empty block of data from a sparse file does not take time; this happens because no data is read from disk; since the file system knows all the bytes in the block are `0`, it just sets to `0` all the bytes in the input buffer and the data is ready; there is no need to access the slow storage device;
- writing an empty block of data into a sparse file does not take time; on writing, the file system detects that the block is empty (all its bytes are `0`) and puts the block ID into the list of empty blocks (in the file meta-data); no data is written to the disk.

More information about sparse files can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).