# Different sizes for /var/lib/docker

Tags: linux, docker

I don't know actually if this is more a "classic" linux or a docker question but:

On an VM where some of my docker containers are running I've a strange thing. /var/lib/docker is an own partitionwith 20GB. When I look over the partition with df -h I see this:

```
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  815M  7.0G  11% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        12G  3.2G  8.0G  29% /
/dev/sda7       3.9G   17M  3.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5       7.8G  6.8G  649M  92% /var
/dev/sdb2        20G   47M   19G   1% /usr2
/dev/sdb1        20G  2.9G   16G  16% /var/lib/docker
```

So usage is at 16%. But when I now navigate to /var/lib and do a du -sch docker I see this:

```
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root# cd /var/lib
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root# du -sch docker
19G     docker
19G     total
eti-gwl1v-dockerapp1 root#
```

So same directory/partition but two sizes? How is that going?

Comment: What filesystem you are using?

Comment: /var/lib/docker itself is ext4, my docker container are using overlay2

Comment: `overlay2` - how do you think "overlay" works? If you count sizes of all files, if you have `dir1` and mount `dir2` as an overlay, how do you think the size will change? How do you think the size on the disc will change?

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question for unix.stackexchange.com, but there is filesystem overhead that makes the partition larger than the total size of the individual files within it.

Answer (score 1):

`du` and `df` show you two different metrics:

- `du` shows you the (estimated) *file space* usage, i.e. the sum of all file sizes
- `df` shows you the *disk space* usage, i.e. how much space on the disk is actually used

These are distinct values and can often diverge:

- *disk usage* may be bigger than the mere sum of file sizes due to additional meta data: e.g. the disk usage of 1000 empty files (file size = 0) is >0 since their file names and permissions need to be stored
- the space used by one or multiple files may be smaller than their reported file size due to:

  - holes in the file - block consisting of only null bytes are not actually written to disk, see [sparse files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982478/what-is-file-hole-and-how-can-it-be-used)
  - automatic file system compression
  - deduplication through hard links or copy-on-write

Since `docker` uses the image layers as a means of deduplication the latter is most probably the cause of your observation - i.e. the sum of the files is much bigger because most of them are shared/deduplicated through hard links.

Answer (score 1):

`du` estimates filesystem usage through summing the size of all files in it. This does not deal well with the usage of overlay2: there will be many directories which contain the same files as contained in another, but overlaid with additional layers using overlay2. As such, `du` will show a very inflated number.

I have not tested this since my Docker daemon is not using overlay2, but using `du -x` to avoid going into overlays could give the right amount. However, this wouldn't work for other Docker drivers, like btrfs, for example.